# Getting error while running amazon-kinesis-producer-sample

Tags: amazon-kinesis-kpl

I tried running [amazon-kinesis-producer-sample](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-producer/tree/master/java/amazon-kinesis-producer-sample)

I used amazon-kinesis-producer version 0.10.2 on Windows7. Getting below error:

```
2017-03-30 14:44:41 [pool-2-thread-2] ERROR c.a.s.k.producer.KinesisProducer - Error in child process
com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.producer.IrrecoverableError: Unexpected error connecting to child process
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.producer.Daemon.fatalError(Daemon.java:502)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.producer.Daemon.access$1200(Daemon.java:61)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.producer.Daemon$6.run(Daemon.java:447)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: \\.\pipe\amz-aws-kpl-in-pipe-5691b4bc
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:79)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:97)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.newFileChannel(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:115)
    at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.open(FileChannel.java:287)
    at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.open(FileChannel.java:335)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.producer.Daemon.connectToChild(Daemon.java:329)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.producer.Daemon.access$1000(Daemon.java:61)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.producer.Daemon$6.run(Daemon.java:444)
    ... 5 common frames omitted
```

what could be the issue here?

Comment: Any solution? I am having the same problem.

Comment: There's an issue with kpl library: https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-producer/issues/39